# Wrong encoding in openshift java app server logs

Tags: jsf, logging, encoding, jboss, openshift

I am testing openshift based simple jsf app with Jbossas server.
But it seems that wrong encoding comes in logs by some reason...
For example, some code from jsf bean method:

```
System.out.println("перед dao.addTask");

System.out.println("name = " + name); // where name value is "экстраординарно"
```

In server logs we have:

> □□□□□□□□□□ dao.addTask
>
> name = □□□□□□□□□□□□□□□

What is the reason for wrong encoding in logs when java code uses utf-8 encoding ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update logger encoding in standalone.xml file. Every OpenShift application has .openshift directory that contains few configuration files and other OpenShift specific files. For JBoss application, there is standalone.xml inside .openshift/config directory. Update following in standalone.xml

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
```

to

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" encoding="UTF-8">
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: There was no periodic-rotating-file-handler entry in original standalone.xml at all. 

Well, I put periodic-rotating-file-handler in <profile><subsystem> group. Then git add standalone.xml, commit, push and recive: jbossas process failed to start...